# Why when I focus input in React value is disappearing?

Tags: reactjs

I have React Component with input

```js
clickButton() {
  const text = this.selectorService.getText() || '';
  this.setState({
    selectedText: text
  });
}
```

```html
<input className="input" type="text" value={this.state.selectedText}/>
```

But when I focus on this input, value is disappearing?

Comment: Can you show more code? How are you dealing with `selectedText` are you using some function that activates on focus?

Comment: Share the code that reproduces your problem

Comment: I have button, when I clicked on button text is added to input, but when I click on input text is lost

Comment: Now I think I understand, my clickButton executed again probably...

Comment: What is `selectorService`, most likely this is coming back as undefined and it's defaulting to the empty string. log it out and see if it's properly getting it.

Comment: @Danyal you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `selectorService`, most likely this is coming back as undefined and it's defaulting to the empty string. log it out and see if it's properly getting it.

That's the reason it's becoming empty, fix the `selectorService` and it'll work as expected.